# Navbar links not selectable in certain parts of my page when the screen width is smaller

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-4

So I'm working on a bootstrap website which can be seen at:

http://stephenhyatt.com/avwood.html

There's 5 parts of the page Home/About Us/Services/Portfolio/Request a Quote. When the page is on a small screen and the navbar collapses to that menu button. I can't select all of the links properly when I'm on some of the pages. For example, on the home page when it's collapsed everything works just fine. However, if I go to the About Us section I can only select the "Portfolio" or "Request a Quote" section. The Request a Quote section only allows me to select the "Portfolio" section. I find this weird because my navbar code is the same for each bar with the exception of the active tag.

Here's my Navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">
    &#9776;
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/AVwood.png" height="40px"></a>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://stephenhyatt.com/avwood.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://stephenhyatt.com/avaboutus.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://stephenhyatt.com/avservices.html">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="http://stephenhyatt.com/avportfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://stephenhyatt.com/avquote.html">Request a Quote</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'm also using:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
```

and

```
   <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `class="nav-item"` to portfolio `<li>` tag.